# json object array undifined error

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I have a JSON object that gets returned by an AJAX request but it keeps returning undefined.

```
{
"shelters": [{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "ksk",
    "introduce": "설정에서 변경해주세요",
    "lonlat": "lon=14135650.08512,lat=4518305.530134",
    "created_at": "2014-10-21T11:30:34.916Z",
    "updated_at": "2014-10-21T12:16:24.943Z"
}, {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "aa",
    "introduce": "설정에서 변경해주세요",
    "lonlat": "lon=14135014.702323,lat=4518095.3283062",
    "created_at": "2014-10-22T16:52:03.912Z",
    "updated_at": "2014-10-22T16:53:07.407Z"
}]
}    
alert(data.length);
alert(data.shelters.length);
alert(data.shelters);
```

Why is the output 'undefined'?

Comment: `shelter` != `shelters`

Comment: Is it possible that you analyze the response **before** it's actually received?  You may want to post the preceding code.

Comment: I bet the reason will be async functions. Could you share more code? where do you get data?

Comment: where is `data` assigned?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/sukyumkim/uut8htb7/ @Fallenreaper

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
var myJson= JSON.parse('{"shelters":[{"id":1,"name":"ksk","introduce":"설정에서 변경해주세요","lonlat":"lon=14135650.08512,lat=4518305.530134","created_at":"2014-10-21T11:30:34.916Z","updated_at":"2014-10-21T12:16:24.943Z"},{"id":2,"name":"aa","introduce":"설정에서 변경해주세요","lonlat":"lon=14135014.702323,lat=4518095.3283062","created_at":"2014-10-22T16:52:03.912Z","updated_at":"2014-10-22T16:53:07.407Z"}]}');

console.log(myJson.shelters[0]);
```

#### Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/robertrozas/kv9fv3jp/1/

Comment: Yes, that should be ok, but if your file is already json, you can skip the parse and use `$.getJson` instead of `$.ajax`

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use `jQuery.getJSON()` instead of `jQuery.ajax()`.